# jquery slider not working for less than 3 images - i.e. one or two

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have following code i am facing issue when images are less than three it shows up blank slide its not working perfectly as a rotators i want it to work like infinite rotator both ways clockwise as well as anticlockwise.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/UszTu/)

**CSS**

```
#slider-wrapper {
    margin: 5% 10%;
    max-height: 500px;
    max-width: 300px;
    position:relative;
}
#slider {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99999;
    max-width: 710px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: red;
}
#button-previous {
    height: 60px;
    left: -40px;
    margin-top: 40%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
}
#button-next {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 40%;
    position: relative;
}
.sp {
    position: absolute;
}
#slider .sp {
    max-width: 710px;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 500px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $("#slider > div:gt(0)").hide();
$("#button-next").click(function () {
    $("#slider > div:first")
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .appendTo("#slider");
});

$("#slider > div:gt(0)").hide();
$("#button-previous").click(function () {
    $("#slider > div:last")
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .appendTo("#slider");
});
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="slider-wrapper">
        <div id="slider">
            <div class="sp"><img src="Images/thumb/1.jpg" width="234" height="240"></div>
            <div class="sp"><img src="Images/thumb/2.jpg" width="234" height="240"></div>
            <div class="sp"><img src="Images/thumb/3.jpg" width="234" height="240"></div>
        </div>
            <div id="button-previous">prev</div>
            <div id="button-next">next</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please do not revert grammar edits correcting your use of "i" for "I" and general lack of punctation.     http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165504/can-a-literate-user-be-encouraged-to-stop-deliberate-writing-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/Mpjz7/2/)

> when images are less than two

Which means you have only one image? To make it work with a single image and make it an infinite loop, use this code:

```
var sliderDivs = $('#slider > div.sp');
var sliderCount = sliderDivs.length;
var currSlide = 0;
$("#slider > div.sp:eq(0)").fadeIn(1000);
$("#button-next").click(function () {
    $("#slider > div.sp:eq(" + currSlide + ")").fadeOut(1000);
    currSlide++;
    if (currSlide > sliderCount - 1) currSlide = 0;
    $("#slider > div.sp:eq(" + currSlide + ")").fadeIn(1000);
});
$("#button-previous").click(function () {
    $("#slider > div.sp:eq(" + currSlide + ")").fadeOut(1000);
    currSlide--;
    if (currSlide < 0) currSlide = sliderCount - 1;
    $("#slider > div.sp:eq(" + currSlide + ")").fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Comment: this working ok for one image - but your fiddle is not working for three images skipping last and showing up empty slide -

Comment: @AamirShahzad this will work for as many images as you want and I've updated the jsFiddle, too.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to remove the next() selector(since you are already using append) and use prependTo for the previous button.

```
  $("#button-next").click(function () {
        $("#slider > div.sp:first")
            .fadeOut(1000)
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .appendTo("#slider");

        $("#slider > div.sp:first")
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .appendTo("#slider");
    });

    $("#slider > div:gt(0)").hide();
    $("#button-previous").click(function () {
         $("#slider > div.sp").fadeOut(1000);
        $("#slider > div.sp:last")
           .prependTo("#slider") 
            .fadeIn(1000);

    });
```

Here is the working fiddle by the way

http://jsfiddle.net/jeremejazz/KZgaq/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/KZgaq/2/ this not working correctly for 1 image - click right or left in a series (5-10 clicks) its shows up an empty slide.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#slider > div:gt(0)").hide();
        $("#button-next").click(function () {
            $("#slider > div:first")
                .fadeOut(1000)
                .next()
                .fadeIn(1000);
            $("#slider > div:first").appendTo("#slider");
        });

    $("#button-previous").click(function () {
        $("#slider > div:first")
            .fadeOut(1000);
        $("#slider > div:last")
            .fadeIn(1000);
        $("#slider > div:first").before($("#slider > div:last"));
    });
});
```